# Oscillation experimetns

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

So currently I have trouble evaluating my experiment because I do not have literature values for my experiment. So the experiment was, I found the relationship between the surface area of the damping system against the half life of the period, that is the time taken for the oscillating body to come to exactly half the amplitude. Using the equation:
$$y=Ae^{-Bt}\sin(Ct+D)+E$$

But after successfully getting this data, I could not evaluate it well as there wasn't much too talk about as I cannot find any literature values online with regards to this experiment I am doing. So my question is, does anyone know any literature values of this experiment where this experiment has been done before?

Comment: You haven't given us any information about the experiment except "it didn't work." We can't answer the question if we don't know what experiment you are talking about!

Comment: Like I got the respective half life values for each respective surface area I used, purely through the equations, but I just can not know how accurate my values are because there are no values I can find online.

Comment: Just look at "damped harmonic oscillator". And how the damping coefficient affects the resonance frequency.